# I can't import CoreLocation

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location, xcode13

[image: CoreLocation doesn't exits]

Firstly,I added corelation.framework later I got permission location privacy from info.plist. I use xcode 13.4.1 and I can't import coreLocation ,it doesn't exist.  therefore ı can't create a object from CLLocationManager class . CoreLocationUI exist but I don't want to use it . How do I fix it ?

Comment: use sensible tags. not too specific, because those aren't watched by anyone. always tag a language. please take the [tour] and review [ask]. further, you really should replace the screenshot by the text it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named your app "CoreLocation", so this is an import of the package itself, not the system's CoreLocation. You should rename your app.